# Assigning a value to nested Object using Deep Partial

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface `User` and I need to build this object instead of assigning all the properties at once.

```
interface User {
    firstName: string;
    address: {
        legalAddress: {
            street: string;
            zipcode: string;
            city: string;
        },
        mailingAddress: {
            street: string;
            zipcode: string;
            city: string;
        }
    };
}

type DeepPartial<K> = {
  [attr in keyof K]?: K[attr] extends object ? DeepPartial<K[attr]> : K[attr];
};

let userOne: DeepPartial<User> = {};

userOne.firstName = "Ron" //this works
userOne.address.legalAddress.city = "NY" // this throws an Undefined error
```

When I assign a value to `userOne.address.legalAddress.city`, I get an error stating that `legalAddress` is undefined. I have used  Deep Partial here, but still this does not work. Is there a way for me to assign a value to nested keys like `userOne.address.legalAddress.city`

Comment: TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime. All you have at runtime is `let userOne = {};`, which indeed does not have an `address` property (certainly not with a value that's an object with a `legalAddress` property with a value that's an object, such that `userOne.address.legalAddress.city = "NY"` could feasibly work).

Comment: One either has to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) a partially valid data-structure to `userOne`, or one needs to programmatically built this structure since, as already mentioned,  `userOne` starts as plain/empty object.